# Defining smoothScroll.init(); in separate file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using smooth-scroll.js and calling `smoothScroll.init();` in my footer in between script tags. Everything works great however I want to move `smoothScroll.init();` to my "site.js" file. However when I do it doesent work and I get an error that `smoothScroll.init();` is not defined. What would I have to do to define it and make it work in site.js. Thanks very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `site.js` script tag is after the `smooth-scroll.js` tag.
If it is before, `smoothScroll.init()` will be called before it is defined.